# How to manage headers in csv.reader()?

Tags: python, csv

Pandas is having some trouble reading in a certain messy csv file, so I'm using the `csv` library.

It is not detecting the header, so it has been inserted into the rows.

All guides to the `csv` library show that you must skip the header using `next()`. But how do I put it back in?

Here's my simple code to read the csv:

```
c = csv.reader(open('card_16092019.csv','r'), delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

How can I keep the header as a header and not part of the rows?

Comment: `header_row = next(c)`  Then when writing rows write the `header_row` before all others.

Comment: I don't write rows, I just use `pd.DataFrame(c)` after I have read the file. Should I use `writer` instead?

Comment: `header_row = next(c); df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(c, columns=header_row)` (That's from my reading of the `pandas` docs. I am not certain if you need to pass `c` or `list(c)`.)